# React state still changing when set via localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Basically I have two buttons, both change my `this.state.language` to either "en" or "es". I have created 2 onClick methods to when changing it, save it to localstorage. However after doing this, when I go to a different page, the state reverts back to the default value.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: ''
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'});
    localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language));
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'});
    localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language));
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

The language state is also being passed into my Routes as a prop

Comment: @adiga Can I just do `this.setState({ language: localstorage.getItem('language')})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `localStorage` value using [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) and set the `language` if it's already been set previously:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    const language = storage.getItem("language") || '';
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'});
    localStorage.setItem('language', this.state.language);
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'});
    localStorage.setItem('language', this.state.language);
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

And you don't need to `JSON.stringify()` since `language` is already a string

Comment: This works, the state keeps its value now when the page is changed, but the following code doesn't work `let jsonLang;
  
        if (this.state.language == 'en') {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        } else if (this.state.language == 'es') {
            jsonLang = data.es;
        } else {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        }
  
        this.placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
        this.counties = jsonLang.counties;
        this.categories = jsonLang.categories;`

So when the state is 'es' and the page is changed, it still displays as if it was 'en'

Comment: What is `data.en`? Does it have properties called `placeholders`, `counties` in them?

Comment: yes it does, here is a paste bin of the page as it is now https://pastebin.com/4x6WK1kY

Answer (score 1):

state is **async**, you can call a function after the state value has updated, try like below:

```
   langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'}, () => localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language)));
  }
```

This is explained in documentation of setState.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

your console and localstorage can't set.

Answer (score 0):

Load the saved state from localStorage in your constructor:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: localStorage.getItem('language') || ''
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You doesnt restore state from storage. You should restore it:

```
...
componentWillMount() {
 this.setState({language: localStorage.getItem('language') || 'en'});
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only things which you need to do is, read the value from local storage for default value. Also `setState` is *async* method and it has a callback, so you have to set data to `localStorage` in there.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: localStorage.getItem('language')
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will for you.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: localStorage.getItem("language")
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("language"));
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'}, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language));
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("language"));
    });
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'}, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language));
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("language"));
    });
  }
```

Here is a working example
https://codepen.io/skalekarr/pen/QoGWeo